# When you reduce the pressure of a liquid below it's saturation pressure within a container, does it boil or evaporate?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, evaporation

I was playing around with a compressed air can, and it made me think of the greater physics behind what *actually* happens when I pull the trigger.

I know that compressed "air" cans actually constitute of a hydrocarbon akin to Freon, and that within the can it exists at it's liquid-vapor equilibrium until you initiate flow, and the pressure of the gas drops below Psat.

I have several questions about the phase transition associated with this action:

1. Once P0 (pressure of the gas) drops below Psat, does the bulk liquid start boiling or does it evaporate from the surface?
2. In terms of energy/mol required, what exactly is the difference between boiling and evaporation? Wouldn't they both require the latent heat of vaporization?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boiling is a type of evaporation that occurs below the liquid surface.

Usually   the evaporation is into microscopic and unnoticeable air-filled cavities in the container wall. As the temperature of the liquid is raised these cavities start to contain much more vapour than air, so the pressure in the cavity is roughly equal to the saturated vapour pressure (SVP). But the vapour is kept in the cavities by the liquid, which acts as a seal with atmospheric pressure (or whatever is the pressure of gas above the liquid) pushing down on it.

If we go on heating the liquid it will reach boiling point. This is the temperature at which the SVP is equal to, or just above, atmospheric pressure (or the pressure of the gas above the liquid). The vapour in the cavities can then expand, forming bubbles that can break free of the container wall and rise to the surface. We have boiling! [The cavities will refill with vapour and so on.]

[Note that we have neglected the effects of depth of liquid and of surface tension.]

So the answer to your Q1 is that if $p_0$ drops below $p_{sat}$ the liquid will indeed start boiling (and will continue to evaporate from the surface).

And, answering your Q2, both evaporation and boiling require latent heat of vaporisation. Remember that boiling is a special type of evaporation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One follow up, in the case of reducing P0 in a constant volume single component system, does the energy required for the phase change come from the liquid itself, or its surroundings (or both!)? I am familiar with the concept of Helium bubbling in cryogenics to achieve subcooling, and I'm equating the two scenarios to being thermodynamically similar...

Comment: Usually both. If the liquid is insulated from its surroundings, the liquid will cool as it evaporates (or boils). This will reduce the svp and the liquid will stop boiling. [Also pressure might build up above the liquid and stop boiling – depending on your set up. Normally, though, heat will flow in from the surroundings so that the temperature comes to an equilibrium value when the latent heat of vaporisation is supplied by the heat inflow.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you very much for your answers :)

Comment: This is typically called "flashing" of the liquid to vapor to indicate the rapidity of the process.